# SSRS Dynamic Tablix/Table using parameters

Tags: reporting-services, report, msbi

I have one scenario in my project SSRS reports, I want to create a tablix or table region based on the multiple parameter values selected from the drop down list. Based on the number of parameters selected from the drop down list, it should create separate table for each parameter vales. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating different tables for each value in the parameters. then just hide the table(s) if it's not selected by the user.

Comment: Thanks Aldrin for the suggestions. I too had same thought on this scenario, what if we have more than 30 values in the drop down, so we cant create 30 table manually in the reports